# Strange use of "aux" in a sentence

Tags: grammaire, accord

I'm reading *Harry Potter et la Chambre des Secrets*, and I came across a grammatical point that confused me.

> J'appartiens aux monde des sorciers… au monde de Poudlard.

*Aux* vs *au*. In English we would be referring to the singular world, so it wouldn't matter if we said world of plural sorcerers or world of singular Hogwarts. Is that not how it works in French?

Comment: Stephane, you are a very thorough editor. I can always count on you to make a question look good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a typo. It should be `au` in both cases :

> J'appartiens au monde des sorciers... au monde de Poudlard.

or (but it looks a bit weird)

> J'appartiens aux mondes des sorciers... au monde de Poudlard.

Comment: I am so psyched right now. I just detected my first typo in French. SO SATISFYING. Thank you.

Comment: @Aerovistae The book must be bad... ;-) Try another.

Comment: @Aerovistae See if you can spot the big error in the first book's Griffondor/Serpentard quidditch match!

Comment: In good time! I'll keep an eye out. :)